# How to edit text in PSD without Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have received some psd files but need to modify the texts.
But I do not have Photoshop. I have Gimp but could not managed to edit the text part.

Is there a way to edit text of a PSD file without Photoshop?

Comment: Can you just ask the person who created the Photoshop files to alter the text for you? That would seem to be the simplest method.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use software that can read the PSD format which, sadly, are few and far between.

You could try Pixelmator, which supports PSD files to an extent. I'm not sure if it can handle text layers, though.

Photoshop Elements might work as well. But, again, I'm not sure.

Also note that you'd need a copy of the fonts used in the original PSD as well.